# EC private key to CngKey in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, cng

I need to convert a EC private key generated by BouncyCastle to a CngKey in C#.  Ultimately, I'm trying to create a PKCS12 that can be imported into the Windows Key Store and am following the information and code example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624105/generate-certificate-using-ecdsa-in-c-sharp).

The EC key pair is generated as follows:

```
    var ecKeyPairGenerator = new ECKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
    ECKeyGenerationParameters ecKeyGenParams = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP384r1, new SecureRandom());
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = ecKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

To create a CngKey:

```
PrivateKeyInfo privKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(pair.Private);
CngKey cngPrivKey = CngKey.Import(privKeyStruct.GetDerEncoded(), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
```

Searching on the web, the above should work, e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414125/export-ec-private-key-from-bouncycastle-and-import-into-cngkey-or-ecdsacng). Instead, I'm getting an Unknown error exception

> (CryptographicException) at
>   `System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.ImportKey()`. If I pass
>   `CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob` to `CngKey.Import()`, I get an
>   invalid data exception.

As a new newbie to both .NET, CNG, and Cryto, I feel I'm overlooking something.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!